# Find clocking errors in org-mode entries: list/edit all clock entries with duration until next day(s)

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-clock

I discovered the excellent [org-analyzer tool](https://github.com/rksm/clj-org-analyzer) and used it to analyze my clock entries in `Emacs org-mode`.

Unfortunately the results are not usable yet, because there are a lot (dozens) of faulty clock entries. Most of them are "over night", so I worked on something in the afternoon, forgot to clock out and then the clock-out was generated the next morning.

My question: how can I get a list of all clock intervals with 2 different dates, e. g.

CLOCK: [2020-07-24 Fri 15:38]--[2020-07-25 Sat 08:38] => 17:00

- How can I create a search agenda to list all of them, so that I can fix them manually?  Criteria would be 2 different days like in the example above. (Or is there some other way in `Emacs` to search all .org files in a directory for such entries and easily edit the faulty lines?)
- or is there already a tool for cleaning up such clock entries in `org-mode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [elgrep](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep) which is available on [Melpa](https://www.melpa.org/#/elgrep).

After a successful install, call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `elgrep-menu` or you click on the menu entry `Tools` → `Elgrep`.

There are two features that make `elgrep` especially suited for that task:

1. Specify whole lines that start with `CLOCK:` as search records.

   - You can do so by setting `Beginning of Record` to `Regexp` and typing `^ *CLOCK:` into the corresponding text field.
   - Also set `End of Record` to `Regexp` and set the text field to `$` to specify the end of line as record end.
2. Instead of a single regexp use a list of regexps with one positive regexp and one negative one.

   - You can leave the positive regexp empty. In that case also `CLOCK`-lines with missing time stamps or with only a single time stamp are detected.
   - An exclamation mark `!` at the beginning of the second regexp negates the regexp. That means that only such records are listed that match the first regexp but **not** the second one. Behind the `!` use a regexp that matches a time interval starting and ending on the same day, i.e., including the exclamation mark
     `!\[\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\).*\]--\[\1.*\]`.

You get all the above settings automatically if you paste the following line into the first `Form:` line of the Elgrep call list and click the `[SET]` button above the input field.

```el
(elgrep/i "~/" "\\.org\\'" ("" "!\\[\\([0-9]\\{4\\}-[0-9]\\{2\\}-[0-9]\\{2\\}\\).*\\]--\\[\\1.*\\]") :r-beg "^ *CLOCK:" :r-end "$" :async t)
```

You just need to replace `~/` in the text field for `Directory` with the right path. Completion by <kbd>M-TAB</kbd> works in that text field.

If you need that kind of search more often for a certain directory I suggest you run the search once and afterwards give the search a name in the Elgrep call list. Those named Elgrep calls are preserved in the call list and you can  even directly run them with the `[RUN]` button.

The search results are listed in the `*elgrep*` buffer. That buffer has an `Elgrep` menu where you can activate `Elgrep-edit` (bound to <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>). Afterwards you can **edit** the clock lines to your liking and save the buffer with <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>. This modifies and saves the matching lines of the original buffers.

Background info: Named elgrep calls are automatically stored in the `elgrep-data-file` relative to the  `user-emacs-directory`.